# Isabelle/HOL using addition/subtraction associativity

Tags: isabelle, formal-verification

I'm trying to prove something of the form

```
lemma assoc: "b + (c - d) = (b + c) - d"
```

AFAIK the associativity theorems are part of the library but aren't marked as simplifications, so I need to to manually add them. What exactly are the names of the appropriate ones / which `theory` are they defined in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such goals are typically solved with the theorem collection `algebra_simps`. Just write `by (simp add: algebra_simps)`.

Note that the way you stated the theorem, you will not be able to prove it because you did not specify that `b`, `c`, and `d` are elements of a group. You will need to write something like

```
lemma assoc: "(b :: 'a :: group_add) + (c - d) = (b + c) - d"
```

or

```
lemma assoc: 
  fixes b c d :: "'a :: group_add"
  shows "b + (c - d) = (b + c) - d"
```

or something more special, like `nat` or `int` instead of `'a :: group_add`.

In fact, when you do that, the IDE will notify you that there is already such a lemma: `Groups.group_add_class.add_diff_eq`

```
thm add_diff_eq
> ?a + (?b - ?c) = ?a + ?b - ?c
```